# Wrap text around graphic without changing its size

Tags: wrapfigure

I created a graphic with specific dimensions and text in it so I don't want to scale it.

I want the text to float around it so I use `\wrapfigure` which needs a specified width, which I want to get from the inserted image (`\includegraphics`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Box the image and then use the width of the box in `wrapfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\wd\mybox}
\usebox\mybox
\caption{a test figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If you are going to use this many times, perhaps you could define an environment to simplify the code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox

%Syntax:
%\begin{Wrapfigure}[<lines>]{<position>}[<overhang>]{<image file>}[<options for image>]
%\caption{description}
%\label{...}
%\end{Wrapfigure}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Wrapfigure}{O{}mO{0pt}mO{}}
  {%
    \savebox\mybox{\includegraphics[#5]{#4}}
    \wrapfigure[#1]{#2}[#3]{\wd\mybox}
    \usebox\mybox
  }
  {\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{Wrapfigure}{r}{example-image-a}[height=4cm]
\caption{a test figure}
\end{Wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{Wrapfigure}[11]{l}[30pt]{example-image-a}[height=3cm]
\caption{a test figure}
\end{Wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your solution. Can you merge these two steps the definition in the preamble and the insertion of the graphic in one command?

Comment: @jhg You're welcome. Yes, one could define that command, but it would end up having three mandatory and three optional arguments, so I don't think it's practical to define it.

Comment: @jhg Perhaps more arguments, since one would also need two more for the caption and one more for the label. No; it's not practical, in my opinion, to define such a command. Perhaps an environment.

Comment: @jhg Please see my updated answer with the definition of an environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort it works like a charm!
I never have used the overhang option but I do use a `\vspace{-_pt}` before inserting the picture to compensate the displacement of images when wrapfigure is directly after a `\section`. So I'll use `#3` for that.